# Hypothesis testing: test difference in frequencies

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, frequency, fishers-exact-test

I have sampled some data, and want to argue that one class of events is more common that another class of events. To get concrete, let's use an example involving text. Suppose I sample some English documents. I want to argue that, in the broader population of English texts, that the letter 'e' occurs at a different rate than the letter 'a'.

Right now I'm using the Fisher exact test, with a contingency over the letter frequencies:

```
     a   ~a
  e  0   n1
 ~e n2   n3
```

Where n1 + n2 + n3 = N (the number of letters in the document)

Does this make sense? I feel like I'm missing something obvious. However, observations come from the same sample. It's not clear to me what constitutes "between groups" in this scenario.

Comment: Welcome to CV! There's no need to apologize for a question, nor to pre-emptively give thanks (the best way to thank someone who gives you an answer that solves your problem is to give them a green uptick to "accept" their answer).

Comment: When you say you are testing for a difference in "frequencies" I think you really mean that you are testing for a difference in *proportions*. That's more in line with the concept of a "different rate".

Comment: I think this is part of my confusion. When I think "difference in proportion", I think: common event, different groups (e.g., disease rates between treated and control group). In my case, I have different events within one common group. I used the term frequency as in letter frequency analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question or the use of contingency tables, but we can refine the answer together, or it can just give you some ideas.

To rephrase, what I think you are asking is along the lines of: Suppose that we know the relative frequency of occurrence of certain letters (let's take vowels) in the English literature at large. We now examine some documents, and we want to see if the counts of these vowels is consistent with the expected frequencies.

Let's simulate some data:

```
               a      e     i      o      u
English     0.34   0.12  0.24   0.11   0.19
documents 256.00 344.00 63.00 223.00 337.00
```

The idea is to run a GoF (goodness-of-fit) test to see if the data conforms to the expected frequencies. And we would do this with a $\chi^2$ test. The degrees of freedom are the number of cells minus $1$.

In `R` we'd run the following command:

```
chisq.test(p = English, documents)

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  documents
X-squared = 612.844, df = 4, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

The squared difference is far too large for the proportion of vowels in your documents to be consistent with the expected proportion in the English literature at large. Perhaps it is because of a very specific linguistic register your documents come from, or because they are very old documents, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed help me work through my requirements.

Comment: Sorry, I hit "Enter" while typing and it submit prematurely. Here's the rest of my thought. In my case I really only have two classes of events that I care about. Let's say 'a' and 'e'. The other 24 letters in the alphabet are observable, but are noise. My null hypothesis is that 'a' and 'e' occur  with the same frequency (i.e., relative frequency 0.50).  I guess we ignore observations that don't satisfy either event?  In this situation the Chi-squared & Binomial test do appear to fit. It was what to do with the  24 letters that was throwing me off. I'll think about this more then accept.

Comment: Please do not accept unless the answer is what you wanted, or just the correct answer. Since I'm having problems visualizing what your experiment is, I'd be surprised if my answer was *it*. I typically up-vote answers that help or try to help, unless they are incorrect or misleading.

Comment: Thanks, I do think my mental block here is one of representation. I'll try one more characterization of my situation: I have a 6-sided dice, which I suspect is loaded. But, I only care about the values 1 and 6. The faces  don't concern me. My null hypothesis is H0: P(X = 1) = p = P(X = 6). My H1: P(X = 1) = p_1 != p_6 = P(X = 6).